# cepstrum analysis to get fundamental freuquency

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum

[image: hilbert->fft->cepstrum]

I am trying to find the fundamental frequency of a bearing fault.This is my code

```
c2=cceps(abs(Signal_fft_hilbert(2:250)));
plot(freq_s(2:250),c2)
```

And this is the cepstrum plot in the image. I have plotted the frequency instead of time. Is that right? And I am not able to identify which should be the fundamental frequency. Theoretically it should be somewhere around 100-123.but I am getting many prominent peaks.
Please help

Comment: what does the signal_fft_hilbert do? Are you doing the cceps of the abs of the fourier transform? I would think you would just apply cceps to the signal directly.

Comment: I am doing bearing faults analysis.so i take hilbert transform and then do the fft.

Comment: cceps is doing an abs and an fft inside of it so it seems like you might not want to do those before you call cceps. I don't know what your original signal is like though

Comment: so in need to take cceps of original signal rather than an fft signal?

Comment: Yes, and plot your output using the original time axis instead of a frequency axis.

Comment: but now the plot is more unclear.because there are noise components also.i plotted for a high pass filter also.still it's a bad plot